# Detecting display type in Android

Tags: android

Is there any mechanism (in either the SDK or NDK) to fetch vendor information (or really, any information) about the current display? In particular, I'm hoping to find if a display is OLED vs. LCD vs. other, as every OLED device I've tested has horrible color fidelity (over-saturation); and since Android doesn't have color correction this needs to be corrected at the app level. As a fallback having a manual list of popular OLED devices and doing a lookup by device type is theoretically feasible, but (a) there's a whole lot of devices out there and (b) working at the device rather than display level adds additional complexity for devices using external displays. Even putting together that list would be a challenge...

Comment: Try `Build.DISPLAY` I've never used it, so I can't vouch for it, but it may contain something useful. [Build docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)

Comment: Build.DISPLAY is apparently intended as "a displayable (to the user) version of the build identifier," not as "an identifier of the physical display."

Comment: I don't think there is any API call for that kind of information. I suppose this is handled by some kind of vendor specific device driver, so perhaps if you check the Android kernel's source code you might find a lead how to access those drivers, but that's only a vague guess and actually doing this might be quite hard core stuff.

Comment: @addaon If you have gained any additional information in the last several months when you began researching this, that would be an interesting update to hear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did went to the Android code and I asked around an can, with a great certainty, say there is is no API method that returns the type of display.

Comment: So no one is even attempting to do color correction on Android?

Comment: @addaon Color management would be a nice feature for Android.  Certainly, it is strongly needed for the various displays out there.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get the information of the physical display of the phone would be to send a get request to a site andparse the HTML/JSON information. You could save it to some kind of online database for future use.
An example of the information on GSMarena.com. Of course you could use other sources.

[image: A sample for my phone (note that you could look for any other for and that the Lumia is just an example.] 
Note that I am not showing an Android phone here but it works the same way.

Answer (score -1):

A lot of the Android `Build` information comes from querying the `/proc` directory. I began poking around in here in hopes to find something - but there is a lot of information to page through. This would be a good place to start - or looking elsewhere on the command line.

You can access the command line by navigating to the `platform-tools` directory, and typing

```
./adb shell
```

when a device is attached. You can also execute shell commands from code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /proc/whatever");
//you can then use p to get the command output.
```