# How to detect an OLED display?

Tags: javascript, display

Is it possible to detect the underlaying screen technology of the user's device in JavaScript? How do I differentiate  between an LCD, e-ink, and OLED display?

Comment: It seems that it's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15052764/5247200) even with an Android API.

Comment: Not too sure if there is a way to directly detecting this, you may have to end up using user agent strings or something.

Comment: @StevenTang - and then check the user agent on a database. My guess is that are not better options.

Comment: I think even the OS can not support this. Maybe the motherboard can do this

Comment: I guess this is possible with a combination of CSS and JavaScript. Though, I have only accomplished it detecting Retina display for Macbooks maybe it can be done with OLED display also.

Comment: Why do you want to know that? Are you sure this is the core of what you really need to know?

Comment: @Kaiido OLED displays use less energy when showing white text on dark backgrounds while LCDs use less energy with black text on white backgrounds. So … I thought I wanted to see if I could deliver a energy-tailored experience for every user.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only option is to use an User Agent database to identify the device and use a Device database to find the corresponding display technology. Maintaining such databases requires a large effort and some of the best ones out there has either a licensing fee or a subscription based API to run queries. The complete solution is therefore likely has a substantial cost and may produce unreliable results and mistakes.

A native API or css media query would be better, but it looks like there's no such thing out there (yet).